# Exporting logs from GCP to Splunk

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, monitoring, splunk

I'm having trouble understand this pricing diagram from GCP: [reference link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/#sink-terms)

I'm trying to export logs directly from the logging API to a Cloud Pub/Sub, but all the documentation I see for achieving this is creating a sink from Stackdriver logging: [reference link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exporting-stackdriver-logging-for-splunk#set_iam_policy_permissions_for_the_cloud_pubsub_topic)

I don't want logs to be ingested into Stackdriver before being exported to a Cloud Pub/Sub as that would incur costs. Am I looking at the diagram correctly or do they not charge for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a simple solution to this problem and that is to exclude and export the logs. I couldn't wrap my head around logs being discarded and at the same time being exported to the Cloud Pub/Sub. Check this link out for the documentation: [documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#stop-logs)

Answer (score 1):

The Logging API *is* an interface into Stackdriver Logs. If you don't want logs to go to Stackdriver, don't use the logging API.

If you want to log from your application to Splunk without going through stackdriver, you will need to build a customer solution that doesn't use the logging API or any of the infrastructure Stackdriver logs provides.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 

In reference to the first link, "there are no costs or limitations in logging for exporting logs." But doesn't this mean logs are already ingested into Stackdriver in order to do this? So would I be incurring costs from Stackdriver? I'm trying to avoid any charges from logs being ingested.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented by transferring logs from logging, then used log router and moved all logs to pub/sub topic. Created Subscription (make it never expire if need continue flow of logs for months) which pulls all the logs from publisher. Then created a dataflow (select pub/sub to splunk dataflow). trigger this dataflow using Airflow or any scheduling tool and that will move all logs to Splunk. Hope this will help